# FluentAssertion. How to verify that two lists have at least one the same element

Tags: c#, json, fluent-assertions

I have expected and actual responses that look like JSON objects by default. In my case there are two lists. I have to verify that this two lists have at list one the same element.

Function should be look like:

```
(expectedResponse, actualResponse) => ((List<Question>)actualResponse.Body).Should()
                        .NotIntersectWith(((List<Question>)expectedResponse.Body))
```

Answer (score 0):

From their [wiki](https://github.com/FluentAssertions/FluentAssertions/wiki#collections), you can use `IntersectWith` method:

```
IEnumerable otherCollection = new[] { 1, 2, 5, 8, 1 };
IEnumerable anotherCollection = new[] { 10, 20, 50, 80, 10 };
collection.Should().IntersectWith(otherCollection);
```

Make sure that objects in collection properly implement `IEquatable<T>` interface (optionaly) and `Equals` method (required).